# One quarter of screen corrupted on MacBook Pro

Tags: display, macbook

I have a problem with my MacBook Pro's screen - here's a video:
http://yfrog.com/4wm63z

For those who prefer words, if you divide the screen vertically into 4 columns, the second column is corrupted (flickering, and discoloured, usually with yellow).

I took it to an Apple store and they said it could be the screen or the logic board, neither of which will be cheap to replace.

However, occasionally this problem will completely go away.  So before I part with my cash, or decide to turn this into an overpriced media center for my TV... could the problem be a loose cable, or something else cheaper to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan, sorry, but based on the evidence I have to agree with the Apple store here -- it's either a bad display or a bad video adapter (and thus motherboard, for laptops).

It couldn't *hurt* to disassemble the laptop and check for a loose display connector of some kind, of course. But it's not likely.

Comment: Thanks for replying Jeff.  Time to start saving up then.  It is strange but it hasn't done it for the last few days.  It seems to go away for days or weeks and then come back for the same amount of time.